# How do you wire a Marx Generator?

Tags: power-supply, power, wiring, electrical

I have seen videos of people actually being able to power on a Marx generator with no problems whatsoever but however they never show the complete setup and diagram of their circuit and real physical layout. So more specifically, how is the power supply wiring done and what are the prerequisites prior to setting up and powering on a Marx generator?

Answer (score 1):

A Marx requires a high voltage DC supply, which can be very low current. You connect it to the first stage with two wires, and everything just works, there's no real need to show a diagram.

There are no special concerns specifically for powering a Marx, only what is needed anyway for any high voltage source - safety, insulation, corona, ozone etc.